# ConstraintLayout Barrier in dynamic feature module fails

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-app-bundle

I have a `ConstraintLayout` within an XML layout, it contains 3 views and a `Barrier`, they are `button2`, `textView2`, `barrier2`, and `button3`. As expected, `button3` is successfully placed under both `button2` and `textView2`, constrained by using `barrier2`. However it seems fail to refer to the constraining views (`button2` and `textView2`) when used in the *dynamic feature* module, so that `button3` sticks to top.

These screenshots show it is successful is base module, but not working in dynamic feature module:

[image: Screenshots]

The XML layouts both in *base* and *dynamic feature* are like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button2,textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, it is success if I set the constraint with code instead of XML:

```
  barrier2.referencedIds = intArrayOf(R.id.button2, R.id.textView2)
```

How to correctly refer to `button2` and `textView2` within the XML layout?

Comment: What is the "dynamic feature module"? Can you give an example of what you are doing and what is not working?

Comment: @Cheticamp modules which contain features and assets that you can decide not to include when users first download and install your app, you can read more at https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

Comment: This bug was corrected into 2.0.0 of ConstraintLayout (Tested with 2.0.0-beta6)

Answer (score 2):

Inspecting the (decompiled) source code, I found a (hacky?) solution: by using fully qualified resource ID (`package:type/entry`). It seems this is not "an official way" since the linter give an error, but it works.

Suppose the app package is `com.example.app` and the dynamic feature module name is `dynfeat`, prepend the ID with `<package>.<module>:id/` like this:

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids="com.example.app.dynfeat:id/button2,com.example.app.dynfeat:id/textView2"
```

I am actually not satisfied with this solution, because code like is hard to maintain, for example, when renaming the dynamic feature module name. So that, the other solution is by subclassing the `Barrier` class and handle it in the constructor.